# Open Paragraphs-item into an entityform

Tags: forms, entities, modal-dialogs, paragraphs

I have a profile page with many paragraph sections. I am trying to open the input form for every paragraph separately into a modal form. I don't want to  manually build a form for each paragraph. The paragraphs on the profile page should open into a modal form after I click a *Edit* link under that paragraphs section. Therefore, Drupal should use its own entity form.

How can I say to Drupal that it should open a paragraph into an entity form?